# WebDriver getCssValue is not returing border color

Tags: xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the border color of a button the HTML properties of the button is like follow

```
<input class="BUTTON" type="button"  title="Add Link" value="Add Link" name="ADD_LINK"/>
```

and CSS properties are as follow

```
background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 solid #EACCAE;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
```

I am using following code for getting `border` property

```
String sColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add Link' and @type='button']")).getCssValue("border");
```

but its not returning any value. At the same place when I am trying to get the background-color property with code

```
 String sColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add Link' and @type='button']")).getCssValue("background-color");
```

it's returning transparent.

Can anyone will please suggest me why I am `not getting border property` or provide me solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS `border` attribute is actually shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color` all together. (See the [W3 doc](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).)

If you query each of those styles individually, you should get back the information you're looking for from Selenium.

Comment: (See also the [WebElement API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)) and the CSS spec it links to)